# Keras translate example to use functional API

Tags: keras

I have a working example in Keras which I want to translate to make use of the functional API. I am missing some detail I when I run the code I get `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` when using embeddings.

Maybe someone sees what I am doing wrong.

The working code looks like this:

```
EMBEDDING_DIM=100
embeddingMatrix = mu.loadPretrainedEmbedding('englishEmb100.txt', EMBEDDING_DIM, wordMap)

###############
# Build Model #
###############
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabSize+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embeddingMatrix], trainable=False))
#model.add(Embedding(vocabSize+1, EMBEDDING_DIM))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(maximal_value)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My attempt to re-write it with the functional API:

```
EMBEDDING_DIM=100
embeddingMatrix = mu.loadPretrainedEmbedding('englishEmb100.txt', EMBEDDING_DIM, wordMap)

input_layer = Input(shape=(longest_sequence,), dtype='int32')
emb = Embedding(vocabSize+1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights=[embeddingMatrix]) (input_layer)
forwards = LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True) (emb)
backwards = LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True) (emb)

common = merge([forwards, backwards], mode='concat', concat_axis=-1)
dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIM, activation='tanh')) (common)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(labelMap), activation='softmax')) (dense)

model = Model(input=input_layer, output=out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

There is somewhere an operation that change the size but I am not sure where or why this is happening. I would be happy if someone could help me with this.

Comment: It seems that you chose to concatenate the forwards and backwards at the `merge` layer. The output of the merge layer will be double size of the previous layer. It doesn't appear to be the way in your original sequential model.